# Monitor/Determine when a com object is used

Tags: c#, winapi, com, mfc

I wonder if any one can help me with this..
What I want to do is to put some type of trigger on a COM object, whenever this object is created/loaded and used, I want to create a log. I am fairly familiar with C# if some one can guide, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean from outside or from inside? I assume the former, as for the latter you just need to add the logging code to the object?

Comment: Well, the constructor of the class that implements the COM object is of course a very obvious place for this kind of code.  If you can't change it then you'll have to limp along with the plain old tools you've got.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use some sniffing tool which enables you to read the RS232 port. There are a lot of free tools available (I used http://www.hhdsoftware.com/serial-monitor, but there are many other tools out there). All you have to do is telling this tool which RS232 port you want to monitor and presto.

If you really have to monitor some RS232 communication from inside your app, it gets a bit more tricky I guess (installing filter drivers and whatnot, which is possibly the highest art of programming under Win32).

Regards,
Stuart

PS: The tag "com" is used for MS's Component Object Model. Better use rs232 as tag name.

Comment: the question was about COM = Component Object Model, not about the COM ports.

Comment: I'm sorry, but logging and COM does make little sense. If you want to log your calls to the COM object, then you can simply add logging code to your app, maybe by adding a logging wrapper to the underlying interface pointer.

Comment: If you want to sniff out how some other COM object is used by another application, you could implement a server that provides objects that only log the calls and forwards them to the real object. However, this may be more difficult as you would have to register your forwarding server under the CLSID of the original COM server. This way, you cannot use the standard COM mechanisms in order to create the real object.

Comment: Thanks all for a reply, I will explain my question in detail here again. What I am trying to do is no illegal sniffing. We have a com objects(with its clsid) that is used from SQL server via a stored procedure, the only way we cannot restrict administrator users to use this object, and users can use query analyzer to use it. I was wondering at windows level, write some tool up using C# etc so that if some one calls this com object then I can log that so that we have a record who called this object, hope this clarifies it.